# How to assure you are closing your functions properly with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone explain to me why I am processing the 50 records but I never get `console.log("all records processed");` to the console.

It is like I am closing a function too soon or too late. What is the best approach when working with call backs because I am sure that is why I do not get `"all records processed"`. I am using node v0.10.26 with the NPM oracle plugin.

```
var oracle = require('oracle');

var connectData = {
    hostname: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 1521,
    database: "xe", // System ID (SID)
    user: "user",
    password: "password"
};

oracle.connect(connectData, function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error connecting to db:", err);
        return;
    }
    connection.setPrefetchRowCount(50);
    var reader = connection.reader("SELECT * FROM CARS", []);
    function doRead(cb) {
        reader.nextRow(function(err, row) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            if (row) {
                // do something with row
                console.log("got " + JSON.stringify(row));
                // recurse to read next record
                return doRead(cb)
            } else {
                // we are done
                return cb();
            }
        });
    }
    doRead(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err; // or log it
        console.log("all records processed");
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with your code, maybe `row` is always 'truthy'?

Comment: No its the oddest thing, you take out the very last command console.log("all records processed"); and the prefetch row works but the connection does not close, there has to be a semicolon needed somewhere!

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried putting the doRead() function in the root namespace instead of embedding inside oracle.connect?

Comment: I agree with Koen. There's nothing that jumps out to me as being clearly wrong. One thing though: I've had to deal with some systems that would swallow exceptions. What I would do in your case is modify the callback passed to `reader.nextRow` so that it starts with `try {` and ends with `} catch (ex) { cb(ex); }` or something similar to that you know if something is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make a difference that you don't have a semicolon after the closing brace of `connectData`? Personally, I just set more and more console logs until I figure out the line that's messing everything up. That, or use breakpoints if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I added the semi. But the odd part is that it behaves differently every time you begin to log it so maybe I am missing another?

Comment: Semicolon after connectData won't have any effect on the control flow at all. In fact, semicolon is useless in almost any case except for when the first character on the next line is `[` or `(`. See http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding .

Answer (score 0):

For these step by step callbacks, I suggest you use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to manage the callback pyramid.

Comment: This is a suggestion, not an answer to the question, so it should be a comment on the question.